# Angular material datepicker multi-year startView

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using angular material datepicker and the startView is month or year but I want the startView to be multi-year to pick a date or birth starting with the year, then month, day

I tried writing some custom code to set the view after opening but I don't think it's possible

```
@ViewChild('picker') picker: any;

test() {
  this.picker.open();
  console.log(this.picker);
  // this.picker.setview('multi-year') would be nice
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[startView]="'multi-year'"
```

don't know how I missed that

Comment: You can also specify it without the square brackets. `startView="multi-year"`

Comment: Is it possible to set startView property in code? my requirement is, once user select Month, calendar should open Year view, not date.